# trouble with Dynamic range in SetterBar

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

It appears that I can set the range to a `Dynamic` variable in a `Manipulate` control, but not in a `SetterBar` control? :

```
Manipulate[
 tick;
 Dynamic@If[ tabNumber == dynTab, Plot[ x^2, {x, 0, 1}],
   Plot[ 1 - x^2, {x, 0, 1}]]
 , TabView[ {
   "dynamic range" -> Column[ tabNumber = dynTab ; {
      Row[{Manipulator[
         Dynamic[m2, (m2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {2, Dynamic@range,
           2}], " ", Dynamic[m2] }],
      Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[s2, (s2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &],
         Range[Dynamic@range]], " ", Dynamic[s1] }]
      }],
   "static range" -> Column[ tabNumber = staticTab ; {
      Row[{Manipulator[
         Dynamic[m1, (m1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {2, 8, 2}], " ",
        Dynamic[m1] }],
      Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[s1, (s1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &],
         Range[8]], " ", Dynamic[s1] }]
      }]
   }, Dynamic @tabNumber ]
 , {{tick, False}, None}
 , {{tabNumber, 1}, None}, {{dynTab, 1}, None}, {{staticTab, 2}, None}
 , {{m1, 2}, None}, {{m2, 2}, None}, {{s1, 2}, None}, {{s2, 2}, None}
 , {{range, 8}, None}
 , TrackedSymbols :> {tick}, ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

This produces an error 'Range::range: "Range specification in Range[range] does not have appropriate bounds. "':

[image: Range error]

Observe that the `Manipulate` in the same tab that uses a `Dynamic` range works fine.  The other tab (not shown in the image) that uses static ranges is fine (for both `Manipulate` and `SetterBar`)?

[EDIT:]

Nasser suggested Evaluate@With[{range = ...}, ...], which assumed range was constant, as in the example above.  Here's an example that is more representitive of what I'm attempting to do (with range based on the count of the number of `Locators` in a `LocatorPane`, which can be added with Alt-Click in that pane).

```
Manipulate[tick;
 If[tabNumber == dynTab, Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}],
  Plot[1 - x^2, {x, 0, 1}]]
 , TabView[{
   "use n-loc as range" -> Column[tabNumber = dynTab; {
      "dynamic range manipulators:",
      Row[{Manipulator[Dynamic[m2, (m2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &],
         Dynamic@{1, 2 range}], " ", Dynamic[m2]}],
      Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[s2, (s2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &],
         Dynamic@Range[range]], " ", Dynamic[s1]}],
      "static range manipulators:",
      Row[{Manipulator[
         Dynamic[m1, (m1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {1, 4}], " ",
        Dynamic[m1]}],
      Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[s1, (s1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &],
         Range[4]], " ", Dynamic[s1]}]
      }],
   "loc" -> Column[tabNumber = staticTab; {
      LocatorPane[ Dynamic[u, (
          u = # ;
          range = (Dimensions[u] // First);
          tick = Not[tick]) &],
       Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
       LocatorAutoCreate -> True,
       ContinuousAction -> False
       ]
      , Row[{"u = ", Dynamic@u}]
      }]
   }, Dynamic@tabNumber]
 , {{tick, False}, None}
 , {{u, {{0.5, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.9}}}, None}
 , {{tabNumber, 1}, None} , {{dynTab, 1}, None} , {{staticTab, 2}, None}
 , {{m1, 2}, None} , {{m2, 2}, None} , {{s1, 2}, None} , {{s2, 2}, None}
 , {{range, 2}, None}
 , TrackedSymbols :> {tick}, ControlPlacement -> Left
 (*use a global (comment out range above to try) ... doesn't work: *)
 (*, Initialization\[RuleDelayed] { range = 2 ; }*)
 ]
```

In this example, I put the Dynamic outside of the Range expression.  This eliminates the error text, but still doesn't work.  The SetterBar shows up as text: SetterBar[2, {1,2}]

Comment: 1. As you have discovered you cannot have `Head` of `Dynamic` within `Range`. 2. It isn't clear from your code why you need to be using `Dynamic` in any case because you only have one static value for `range`. Since it doesn't change it doesn't need updating. 3. If you modify your code to allow multiple values of `range` then try `Dynamic[SetterBar[Dynamic[s2, (s2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], 
  Range[range]], TrackedSymbols :> {range}]`

Comment: I'd added the second example to illustrate why I wanted a Dynamic Range.  Your comment is really an answer, since Dynamic@SetterBar does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dynamic[SetterBar[Dynamic[s2, (s2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], Range[range]], 
TrackedSymbols :> {range}]
```

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with evaluation for controls settings and the order Manipulate reads the controls and when things gets evaluated initially. That is why you'll see all settings for controls use hardcoded numerical values right there, since these have their values known at the instance they are read. I've always had hard time with this part.

But to make a long story short, since your `range` value is constant, and not used anywhere, other than just for the control setting, a simple workaround, and I think the correct way to do this anyway, is to use `With`, like this:

```
Manipulate[
 tick;

 If[tabNumber == dynTab,
  Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}], Plot[1 - x^2, {x, 0, 1}]
  ],

 Evaluate@With[{range = 8},
   TabView[
    {
     "dynamic range" -> Column[tabNumber = dynTab;
       {Row[{Manipulator[Dynamic[m2, (m2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], 
       {2, range, 2}], " ", Dynamic[m2]}], 
        Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[s2, (s2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], Range[range]], 
        " ", Dynamic[s2]}]}
       ],

     "static range" -> Column[tabNumber = staticTab;
       {Row[{Manipulator[Dynamic[m1, (m1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], {2, 8, 2}],
        " ", Dynamic[m1]}], 
        Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[s1, (s1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], Range[range]], 
        " ", Dynamic[s1]}]}
       ]
     },
    Dynamic@tabNumber
    ]
   ],

 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{tabNumber, 1}, None},
 {{dynTab, 1}, None},
 {{staticTab, 2}, None},
 {{m1, 2}, None},
 {{m2, 2}, None},
 {{s1, 2}, None},
 {{s2, 2}, None},
 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See if the above works for you.

btw, you do not need to add `Dynamic` to the `If` statement above. So I removed it.
Also, for your TabeView, you can use `Grid` to layout the controls below each tab, much easier than used `Column` and `Rows`, but these are side issues. Here is a version using `Grid`

```
Manipulate[
 tick;

 If[tabNumber == dynTab,
  Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}], Plot[1 - x^2, {x, 0, 1}]
  ],

 Evaluate@With[{range = 8},
   TabView[
    {
     "dynamic range" ->
      Grid[{
        {Manipulator[Dynamic[m2, (m2 = #; tabNumber = dynTab; tick = Not[tick]) &], 
        {2, range, 2}], Dynamic[m2]},
        {SetterBar[Dynamic[s2, (s2 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], Range[range]], 
        Dynamic[s2], SpanFromLeft}
        }, Alignment -> Left],

     "static range" ->
      Grid[{{
         Manipulator[Dynamic[m1, (m1 = #; tabNumber = staticTab; tick = Not[tick]) &],
         {2, 8, 2}], Dynamic[m1]}, 
         {SetterBar[Dynamic[s1, (s1 = #; tick = Not[tick]) &], Range[range]], 
         Dynamic[s1], SpanFromLeft}
        }, Alignment -> Left]
     },
    Dynamic@tabNumber
    ]
   ],

 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{tabNumber, 1}, None},
 {{dynTab, 1}, None},
 {{staticTab, 2}, None},
 {{m1, 2}, None},
 {{m2, 2}, None},
 {{s1, 2}, None},
 {{s2, 2}, None},
 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```

Comment: I actually want range to be non-constant, set as a side effect of an Alt-click in a LocatorPane (trying the Evaluate@With[{range = 2 n},...], where n is a different Manipulate variable produces the same error.  The answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13658/enabled-option-for-slider-in-manipulate-not-updating-dynamically?rq=1 seems to suggest that this is an acknoledged Mathematica bug (where the suggested work around is to use a global variable).

Comment: @PeeterJoot You say `I actually want range to be non-constant`. Ok, but in the code you posted, range was not used anywhere else other than in setting the controls. So that is why I assumed it constant. Ofcourse using range as global will always work, but if you making a demo, you can't have a global cell in the demonstration notebook and everything has to be inside the Manipulate. Even in the Initialization section, it will not work due to order of evaluation. May be it is a bug then for this control. If your setting allows using global variables, then may be this a solution you can use.

Comment: I've posted a more representative sample.

Comment: fyi.  The Dynamic@If is required if you want the plot to update on click of the Tab.  Without that it doesn't update until you click on one of the controls within that tab.