# Not seeing plot of solution returned by NDSolve

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, parametric-functions

I am having trouble with generating a parametric plot with the following code:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{s0, γ, sol, s, i, t},
  s0 = 1 - i0; γ = 1/l; 
  sol = NDSolve[
    {s'[t] == -β/(E^(k (t - τ)))*s[t]*i[t],
     i'[t] == β/(E^(k (t - τ)))*s[t]*i[t] - γ*i[t],
     s[0] == s0, i[0] == i0}, {s, i}, {t, 0, 150}]; 
  ParametricPlot[{s[t] /. sol, i[t] /. sol},
   {t, 0, 30}]],
 {{i0, 0.001, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(0\)]\): infected at the beginning"},
  0, 0.1, 0.001, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{β, 1.5, 
   "β: transmission rate"}, 0.5, 5, 0.5,
  ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{l, 3, 
   "1/γ: infectious period (in days)"}, 1, 7, 
  1, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{k, 0.003, "k: control rate (per day)"}, 
  0, 0.01, 
  0.001, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{τ, 0, "τ: delay (in days)"}, 
  0, 5, 
  1, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

After I ran the code, nothing appeared in the graph box, like so:
[image]

Comment: have you been able to run the `NDSolve[]`and/or the `ParametricPlot[]` outside the Manipulate (I mean as a stand-alone code)?

Comment: Also, I don't believe you need `DynamicModule[]` for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
  sol = NDSolve[ ___ ]  ... By  sol = First@NDSolve[ ___ ]
```

result:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, and could you explain to me what First@NDSolve means and why it works in this situation when NDSolve doesn't work?

Comment: @BohanLu To put it in simple words: you show us a piece of code displaying some mastery of Mathematica. We (the readers) in absence of a sentence stating that you aren't the author, answer in a straightforward way because you _should_ be able to understand that. Then you ask a really first-day-with-Mathematica question. Something doesn't compute here.

Comment: I appreciate your patience. I am indeed a novice in Mathematica and I learned the code above from a paper. I was trying to modify the code a little bit to solve my problem and after referring to the documentation I still wouldn't be able to work it out. I wonder if you have any advice in regard to asking appropriately on this site? Do I have to tell people that I am a novice and cite the code I use every time? I mean, I understand people usually post high-quality and well-thought-out questions here, yet I really don't know another place to find experts like you to help  me.

Comment: For example this question is nothing to do with SIR models, but is a simple misunderstanding of some input/ouptut of a function. Reduce your code to the simplest possible and then post the question. Learn to identify exactly where the problem lies.

Answer (score 7):

Your code can be simplified. In particular, I recommend that you get rid of the embedded `DynamicModule` and, instead, use a common trick of defining invisible controls to localize temporary variables.

```
Manipulate[
  s0 = 1 - i0;
  γ = 1/l;
  sol = NDSolve[{
    s'[t] == -β/(E^(k (t - τ)))*s[t]*i[t], 
    i'[t] == β/(E^(k (t - τ)))*s[t]*i[t] - γ*i[t], 
    s[0] == s0, i[0] == i0}, 
    {s, i}, {t, 0, 150}];
  ParametricPlot[{sol[[1, 1, 2]][t], sol[[1, 2, 2]][t]}, {t, 0, 30}],
  {s0, None}, {γ, None}, {sol, None}, (* invisible controls *)
  {{i0, 0.001,"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(0\)]\): infected at the beginning"}, 
    0.001, 0.1, 0.001, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{β, 1.5, "β: transmission rate"}, 0.5, 5, 0.5, 
    ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{l, 3, "1/γ: infectious period (in days)"}, 1, 7, 1, 
    ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{k, 0.003, "k: control rate (per day)"}, 0, 0.01, 0.001, 
    ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{τ, 0, "τ: delay (in days)"}, 0, 5, 1, 
    ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: manipulate]

Comment: {s0, None}, {γ, None}, {sol, None}, (* invisible controls *)  Invisible Controls!  This looks interesting, but I can't quite see what it does.  Can you elaborate/explain?

Comment: Thinking more about this.  Does this just create additional variables within the `Manipulate` to which one can assign any value?  Couldn't one achieve the same thing by wrapping the `Manipulate` in `Module`?  (I do like this shortcut of yours)

Comment: @Jagra. You are correct in thinking that specifying an invisible control creates a dynamic variable localized to the `Manipulate` that can be used in the same way a localized variable declared in the first argument of a `DynamicModule` can be used, As for wrapping a `Manipulate` in a `Module` to introduce localized variables, there are situations when that can cause serious problems. Read the comments to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13658/3066) for further info.

Comment: The comments to the question you referenced explain a number of funny behavior I've witnessed in the past.  Thanks for the explanation and the warning.