# Difficulty with Manipulate that has same variables as other code lines in a notebook

Tags: differential-equations

If I write this:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == (0.4 - 0.01 s[t]) f[t], 
    s'[t] == (-0.3 + 0.005 f[t]) s[t], f[0] == 40, s[0] == 20}, {f[t],
     s[t]}, {t, 0, 80}];
r[t_] = sol;
```

Then do this:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[sol, {t, 0, 80},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 140}, {0, 100}}],
  Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[tau]}], 
    Arrow[{r[tau], r[tau] + r'[tau]}]}]
  ],
 {{tau, 0}, 0, 80}]
```

I get a nice Manipulate I can use for a classroom demonstration.

[image]

However, if I later use the sol variable to draw another image (a Plot, a ParametricPlot), the new sol value interferes with the Manipulate demonstration.
For example, if the next cell in the notebook has:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == y[t], y[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1, 
   y[0] == -1}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Then this version of sol is now used in the Manipulate demonstration above. So, I tried the following:

```
Manipulate[Module[{sol, r},
  sol = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == (0.4 - 0.01 s[t]) f[t], 
     s'[t] == (-0.3 + 0.005 f[t]) s[t], f[0] == 40, 
     s[0] == 20}, {f[t], s[t]}, {t, 0, 80}];
  r[t_] = sol;
  Show[ParametricPlot[sol, {t, 0, 80},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 140}, {0, 100}}],
   Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[tau]}], 
     Arrow[{r[tau], r[tau] + r'[tau]}]}]
   ]],
 {{tau, 0}, 0, 80}]
```

But it doesn't work. I get an error that I just cannot understand.

Coordinate {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 80.}}, {5, 7, 1, {353}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False}, {{0., 0.0005236906903058783, 0.0010473813806117565`, 0.002094762761223513, 0.0031421441418352696`, 0.004189525522447026, 0.014663339328564591`, 0.02513715313 should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Any thoughts?

Sjoerd C. de Vries suggestion in comments:

```
Module[{sol, r}, 
 Manipulate[
  sol = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == (0.4 - 0.01 s[t]) f[t], 
     s'[t] == (-0.3 + 0.005 f[t]) s[t], f[0] == 40, 
     s[0] == 20}, {f[t], s[t]}, {t, 0, 80}];
  r[t_] = sol;
  Show[ParametricPlot[sol, {t, 0, 80}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 140}, {0, 100}}], 
   Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[tau]}], 
     Arrow[{r[tau], r[tau] + r'[tau]}]}]], {{tau, 0}, 0, 80}]]
```

Still gives the error:

Coordinate {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 80.}}, {5, 7, 1, {353}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False}, {{0., 0.0005236906903058783, 0.0010473813806117565`, 0.002094762761223513, 0.0031421441418352696`, 0.004189525522447026, 0.014663339328564591`, 0.02513715313 should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

**Michael E2:** If I run Michael E2 suggestion it works.

```
Clear[r];
sol = First@
   NDSolve[{r'[
       t] == ({0.4, -0.3} + {{0, -0.01}, {0.005, 0}}.r[t]) r[t], 
     r[0] == {40, 20}}, r, {t, 0, 80}];
With[{sol = sol}, 
 Manipulate[
  Show[ParametricPlot[r[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 80}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 140}, {0, 100}}], 
   Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[tau]}], 
      Arrow[{r[tau], r[tau] + r'[tau]}]} /. sol]], {{tau, 0}, 0, 80}]]
```

[image]

Then if sol gets changed in the global workspace, it doesn't affect Michaels first graph. Note there are very minor changes.

```
sol = First@
   NDSolve[{r'[
       t] == ({0.4, -0.3} + {{0, -0.01}, {0.002, 0}}.r[t]) r[t], 
     r[0] == {40, 20}}, r, {t, 0, 80}];
With[{sol = sol}, 
 Manipulate[
  Show[ParametricPlot[r[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 80}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 140}, {0, 100}}], 
   Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[tau]}], 
      Arrow[{r[tau], r[tau] + r'[tau]}]} /. sol]], {{tau, 0}, 0, 80}]]
```

Which gives this graph, but doesn't change the first graph.

[image]

However, if I now run m_goldberg's script, with slight numerical changes.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 80}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 140}, {0, 100}}], 
  Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[tau]}], 
    Arrow[{r[tau], r[tau] + r'[tau]}]}]], {{tau, 0}, 0, 80}, 
 Initialization :> (r =.; 
   r[t_] = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == (0.4 - 0.001 s[t]) f[t], 
      s'[t] == (-0.3 + 0.05 f[t]) s[t], f[0] == 40, 
      s[0] == 20}, {f[t], s[t]}, {t, 0, 80}])]
```

Then all three images look like this:

[image]

Moreover, if I go back to the first image and try to run the code again, I get this error:

ReplaceAll::reps: {False,True} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

ReplaceAll::reps: {False,True} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

ReplaceAll::reps: {False,True} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Which can be fixed if I Clear[r].

So, still having problems with more than one Manipulate in one notebook.

Comment: Put the Module outside of the manipulate (let it surround it). Better yet, use DynamicModule instead.

Comment: I think I did try that (see my edit above), but I still could not get it to work. Replacing Module with Dynamic Module doesn't work either. Some strange other thing is going on?

Comment: Hint: for the understanding of the error message,  the  list of reals in the error message should be a pair of numbers refers to the result  of  r[tau] that used within the Graphics function. It looks like if r[tau] does not return a pair of numbers, when sol is defined as a local variable using the Module construct.  Sorry I don't have solution but this for clarifying the meaning of the error.

Answer (score 4):

You should not wrap a `Manipulate` expression with `Module`. Read the comments to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13658/3066) to learn why. You can fix your problem by clearing `r` and making a definition of `r[t]` in the initialization section of your `Manipulate` expression. Like so:

```
r = 42;
Manipulate[
  Show[
    ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 80}, PlotRange -> {{0, 140}, {0, 100}}], 
    Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[tau]}], 
                Arrow[{r[tau], r[tau] + r'[tau]}]}]],
  {{tau, 0}, 0, 80},
  {r, None},
  Initialization :> (
    r =.;
    r[t_] = 
      NDSolveValue[{
        f'[t] == (0.4 - 0.01 s[t]) f[t], s'[t] == (-0.3 + 0.005 f[t]) s[t], 
        f[0] == 40, s[0] == 20}, 
        {f[t], s[t]}, {t, 0, 80}])]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: OK, this one does NOT work. To see what I am talking about, create a notebook file and enter your code and run it. Then add the following code after your first Manipulate demo, run it, and you will see it changes the plot in both demos.  My comment is too long, so I will put the code in a second comment.

Comment: Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 80}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 140}, {0, 100}}], 
  Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[tau]}], 
    Arrow[{r[tau], r[tau] + r'[tau]}]}]], {{tau, 0}, 0, 80},
 Initialization :> (r =.;
   r[t_] = 
    NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == (0.4 - 0.001 s[t]) f[t], 
      s'[t] == (-0.3 + 0.05 f[t]) s[t], f[0] == 40, 
      s[0] == 20}, {f[t], s[t]}, {t, 0, 80}])]

Comment: @David. Sorry, I forgot to localize the variable `r`. I have edited my answer to fix the omission by adding the control definition `{r, None}`

Comment: Thanks for that link and comments of John Fultz.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Now it is working. I've still got a lot to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I might approach it like this.  First I like to use the replacement `Rule` form of `NDSolve`.  Since the solution is used as a vector, it makes sense to have `NDSolve` return the vector solution `r`.  Using `With` to inject the solution removes the dependence of the `Manipulate` on an external symbol.  Then `sol` can be reused without affecting this `Manipulate`.  For increased security, replace all the `r` by `\[FormalR]`.

```
sol = First@NDSolve[{
  r'[t] == ({0.4, -0.3} + {{0, -0.01}, {0.005, 0}}.r[t]) r[t], r[0] == {40, 20}},
  r, {t, 0, 80}];
With[{sol = sol}, 
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   ParametricPlot[r[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 80}, PlotRange -> {{0, 140}, {0, 100}}], 
   Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, r[tau]}], Arrow[{r[tau], r[tau] + r'[tau]}]} /. sol]
  ],
  {{tau, 0}, 0, 80}]
 ]
```

Comment: @Micheal E2: Ok, that worked. And so did this: sol = NDSolveValue[{r'[
      t] == ({0.4, -0.3} + {{0, -0.01}, {0.005, 0}}.r[t]) r[t], 
    r[0] == {40, 20}}, r, {t, 0, 80}];
With[{sol = sol}, 
 Manipulate[
  Show[ParametricPlot[sol[t], {t, 0, 80}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 140}, {0, 100}}], 
   Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, sol[t]}], 
     Arrow[{sol[t], sol[t] + sol'[t]}]}]], {{t, 0}, 0, 80}]]

Comment: @Micheal E2: I understood everything you did except the With[{sol=sol}, part. Why does that work? I am not understanding why that protect an outer sol from coming in and ruining the Manipulate demo.

Comment: Still having some problems. See my edits in the original post question.

Comment: @David `With` replaces the symbols defined with their values before the body is evaluated. It is as if the symbols are not really created inside the kernel; more precisely, the code that `Manipulate` sees does not have the symbol `sol` in it. For whatever reason, you can reuse symbol names (`With[{x = x},...]`). See  [559](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559) for more. -- I'm not sure what problem you're having. Is it the `PlotRange` when the parameters of the ODE are changed? If you don't need to save `sol` for use outside `Manipulate`, try `With[{sol = First@NDSolve[...`