# How many ODEs can NDSolve handle?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to simulate a coupled system of `N` blocks and springs. I am using `NDSolve`. For `N = 25` everything goes smoothly, however for `N > 25` it doesn't work. No error message, no warning, just the usual **beep**.

Is there any limitation on the number of ODEs `NDSolve` can handle? (I'm using V9.0.1.0, Home Edition.)

**UPDATE:** The problem is not related with some kind of restriction on `NDSolve`, I just checked it with a more simpler system and `n=500`; NDSolve worked fine. What follows is the code; as I said before for `n=25` it works well, in less than a second, however for `n>26` It doesn't. `Why the beep?` says : `The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation`

```
n = 26;
U0 = 20;
Nt = 3; 
b = 0.5;
umax = 2;
tr = 40.0;


S4 = Join[{u[1]''[t] == 
 1/Nt (U0*(1 - Exp[-(t/tr)]) - u[1][t]) - 
  2*u[1][t]*
   HeavisideTheta[2*umax - Abs[2*u[1][t]]] + (u[n][t] - 
    u[1][t]) + (u[2][t] - u[1][t]) - b*u[1]'[t], 
u[2]''[t] == 
 1/Nt (U0*(1 - Exp[-(t/tr)]) - u[2][t]) - 
  2*u[2][t]*
   HeavisideTheta[2*umax - Abs[2*u[2][t]]] + (u[2 - 1][t] - 
    u[2][t]) + (u[2 + 1][t] - u[2][t]) - b*u[2]'[t],
u[3]''[t] == 
 1/Nt (U0*(1 - Exp[-(t/tr)]) - u[3][t]) + (u[3 - 1][t] - 
    u[3][t]) + (u[3 + 1][t] - u[3][t]) - b*u[3]'[t]
}, Table[
u[i]''[t] == 
 1/Nt (U0*(1 - Exp[-(t/tr)]) - u[i][t]) - 
  2*u[i][t]*
   HeavisideTheta[2*umax - Abs[2*u[i][t]]] + (u[i - 1][t] - 
    u[i][t]) + (u[i + 1][t] - u[i][t]) - b*u[i]'[t], {i, 4, 
 n - 1}],
{u[n]''[t] == 
 1/Nt (U0*(1 - Exp[-(t/tr)]) - u[n][t]) - 
  2*u[n][t]*
   HeavisideTheta[2*umax - Abs[2*u[n][t]]] + (u[1][t] - 
    u[n][t]) + (u[n - 1][t] - u[n][t]) - b*u[n]'[t]},
Table[u[i][0] == 0, {i, 1, n}],
Table[u[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 1, n}]];
Sol = NDSolve[S4, Table[u[i], {i, 1, n}], {t, 0, 70}, 
Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[u[i][t], {i, 1, n}] /. Sol], {t, 0, 70}]
```

Comment: You may be running out of memory.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: For example:

    n=10;$$ $$

    func = ToExpression@Table["f" <> ToString[i] <> "[x]", {i, 0, n}]; $$ $$


    NDSolve[Flatten@{D[#[[1]], x] == #[[2]] & /@ 
     Transpose@{func, RotateLeft@func}, (# /. x -> 0) == 1 & /@ func},
   func, {x, 0, 1}] // Short $$ $$

works fine for any number of ODE's (I checked up to $n=1000$). This system of ODE's is $f'_{i-1}(x)=f_i(x)$, with $f_i(0)=1$.

Comment: Have you tried the menu command, `Help -> Why the Beep?...`?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform You're right, I just checked it with a more simpler coupled system of ODEs and NDSolve worked fine for N=500. So the problem is not the number of equations.

Comment: @MichaelE2 **Why the beep?** shows: **The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation** I'm gonna check that.

Comment: Instead of writing out the same equation multiple times, write it in vector form. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78641/vector-form-using-ndsolve

Answer (score 3):

Finally I realized that the problem is not related directly with NDSolve but with RungeKutta method and HeavisideTheta function. I changed the latter by a more "softer" function:

```
(1 + Tanh[p (1 - (x/xmax))])/(1 + Tanh[p])
```

where p is a number that measures the stiffness of the function and xmax is approximately the zone where the function goes to zero.  Now I can work with hundreds of ODE´s with no problem.