# NDSolve mixing many scalar and vector equations

Tags: differential-equations, vector

I have a set of scalar equations in many unknowns, which I want to combine with a vector equation inside an NDSolve. The equations are a mix of differential and algebraic equations.

A set of scalar equations:

```
eqns = {-a[0][t] + a[1][t] == 0, a[1]'[t] == - fx[1][t] + fy[1][t] - a[1][t],
        a[2]'[t] == - fx[2][t] + fy[2][t] - a[2][t], a[2][t] + a[3][t] == 0,
        0 == x[0][t], a[1][t] == - x[0][t] + x[2][t], a[2][t] == - x[1][t] + x[3][t], 
        a[3][t] == x[1][t] + x[3][t], 1 == y[0][t], a[1][t] == - y[0][t] + y[2][t], 
        a[2][t] == - y[1][t] + y[3][t], a[3][t] == -y[2][t] + y[3][t]};
```

Along with a vector equation, defined using a function fCalc.

```
feqn = {{fx[0][t], fy[0][t]}, {fx[1][t], fy[1][t]}, {fx[2][t], fy[2][t]}, {fx[3][t], fy[3][t]}} == 
      fCalc[{{x[0][t], y[0][t]}, {x[1][t], y[1][t]}, {x[2][t], y[2][t]}, {x[3][t], y[3][t]}}];
```

My actual function fCalc is complicated, but it only evaluates for numerical input. It takes a list of {x,y} points and returns a list of {x,y} points, for instance:

```
fCalc[pts_ /; MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ]] := pts
```

Some initial conditions and the variables used:

```
initcs = {a[0][0] == 0, a[1][0] == 0, a[2][0] == 0, a[3][0] == 0};
vars=Flatten[Table[{a[j], x[j], y[j], fx[j], fy[j]}, {j, 0, 3}]];
```

Trying to solve this directly gives an error, as Mathematica tries to evaluate this vector function before starting, and refuses to start as it doesn't see enough equations for the unknowns.

```
NDSolve[{eqns, feqn, initcs},vars, {t, 0, 1}];
NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.
```

Removing the numerical requirement the system is well-defined:

```
fCalc2[pts_] := pts
AbsoluteTiming[NDSolve[{eqns, feqn /. fCalc -> fCalc2, initcs}, vars, {t, 0, 1}];]
```

So my question is, how to I trick Mathematica into waiting to evaluate the NDSolve until after giving values to the variables, and without having to repeatedly evaluate the fCalc function. There is an answer for solving for a vector system at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78641/vector-form-using-ndsolve), but I can't write my whole system in terms of a derivative of a vector as in that case.

My actual system is much more complicated (see the initial version of this question if you want to see), but I definitely need the numerical restriction on fCalc.

Comment: Can you provide a simplified version of your code that still illustrates the essential issues?  Few readers will undertake to address so much code.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, I have condensed it further, I'm loathe to go further as I think it'll lose the actual structure that I need.

Comment: You can try a numerical solution like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114536/using-data-from-ndsolve-into-a-secondary-equation/114683#114683)

Comment: Yes, I could do the timestepping myself, but I would like to use NDSolve so I don't have to

Comment: Hmm, nobody have an answer for me? There is a sweet sweet bounty available...

Comment: Is `fCalc[]` an algebraic, differential, or some other sort of function?

Comment: I've investigated your original code and I think I have an answer for you, but unfortunately it has only 2 ways: a) rewrite the whole thing into vector notation, b) use primitive symbol constructs for variable names (e.g. x0 instead of x[0]). Both answers worth a lot of work. As a side note, IMHO you should never use compound symbol names while in equation solving problems. I've been there already while doing numerical methods and statistics labs in university -- you either respect vector notation or create hundreds of symbols for each variable, that's the current state of art :(

Comment: @dahnoak, I would love to see your option two.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, I am trying to use something of the form
fCalc[pts_?NumericQ]:=-(Normalize /@ (RegionNearest[line][pts] - pts))  RegionDistance[line][pts], where line is a Line[] primitive.

Comment: The main issue I have with writing the equations into a vector form is that I have boundary conditions which don't involve derivatives (my equations come from discretizing PDEs using Method of Lines), see the first and fourth equations in the current equation.

Answer (score 2):

The system of equations can be solved following the procedure in the accepted answer to [question 78641](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78644/1063).  First, observe that the ODEs in `eqns` all have the form,

```
a[i]'[t] == - fx[i][t] + fy[i][t] - a[i][t]
```

and so can be written in vector form,

```
a'[t] == - fx[t] + fy[t] - a[t]
```

Consequently, the solution is given by

```
NDSolve[{a'[t] == -a[t] - fCalc[a[t]], a[0] == {0, 0}}, a, {t, 0, 1}]
```

where the function `fCalc[a[t]]` returns the array of values `fx[t] - fy[t]` corresponding to `a[t]`.  This function has the form,

```
fCalc[pts : {_?NumberQ ..}] := Module[{l = Length[pts], s}, Do[a[i] = pts[[i]], {i, l}]; 
    s = Solve[eqsim, varsim] // Flatten; ...]
```

where `...` represents whatever code the OP uses to compute `fx - fy`, given values of `x` and `y`.  For instance, if the process were simply to set `fx` equal to `x` and `fy` equal to `y`, then `...` would be `Table[(x[i] - y[i]) /. s, {i, l}]`.  `eqsim` is `eqns` with the ODEs removed, and `varsim` is a `List` of the `x` and `y` variables and the `a` variables not appearing in the ODEs.

For the equations given in the question, this reduces to

```
Clear[a]
eqsim = Delete[eqns, {{2}, {3}}] /. {a[i_][t] -> a[i], x[i_][t] -> x[i], y[i_][t] -> y[i]};
varsim = Join[Flatten[Table[{x[j], y[j]}, {j, 0, 3}]], {a[0], a[3]}];
fCalc[pts : {_?NumberQ ..}] := Module[{l = Length[pts], s}, Do[a[i] = pts[[i]], {i, l}]; 
    s = Solve[eqsim, varsim] // Flatten; Table[(x[i] - y[i]) /. s, {i, l}]];

NDSolve[{a'[t] == -a[t] - fCalc[a[t]], a[0] == {0, 0}}, a, {t, 0, 1}];
Plot[a[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {t, a}]
```

[image]

(The curves for `a[1]` and `a[2]` coincide.)

Comment: I thought of this, but I was searching for a way to get `NDSolve` to handle mixed dimensions.

Comment: @MichaelE2 If you cannot find a better way, I do not know who could.  Certainly, I tried, but without success.

Comment: Thanks for having a go. I think I may be able to adapt this to my case, with having all the algebraic equations solved inside the vector function. In general, I have a'[t] == (finite difference approximation of a spatial derivative, including pieces of a,x,y), not having the nice structure that the reduced example did.

Comment: @KraZug  The entire right side of the ODE for `a[t]` can be computed by `fCalc[]`, so the method in my answer should work in general.  I agree that a more elegant approach would be preferable, but I (and Michael E2, it would appear) each tried hard to find one but without success.

Comment: I'll give it a go next week, I'm away for a few days. Thanks for your help (and @MichaelE2).