# Using data from NDSolve into a secondary equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have this ODE,

```
f''''[y]+Z1*(6 f''[y]*f'''[y]*f'''[y]+3 f''[y]*f''[y]*f''''[y])- N1*N1*f''[y] == 0
```

subject to boundary conditions

```
f[h2] == F1/2, f[h1] == -(F1/2), f'[h1] == 0, f'[h2] == 0
```

where

```
h1 = -1 - m*x - a*Sin[2*\[Pi]*(x - t) + \[Phi]]
h2 = 1 + m*x + b*Sin[2*\[Pi]*(x - t)]

F1 = Q1 + a*Sin[2*\[Pi]*(x - t)]+b*Sin[2*\[Pi]*(x - t) + \[Phi]]
Z1 = 0.002; N1 = Sqrt[M1^2 + (1/k)]; m = 0.25; \[Phi] = 2 \[Pi]/3;k = 0.8;a = 0.3; b = 0.4;
```

The secondary equation is

```
SE = D[f[y], {y, 3}] + Z1*D[f[y], {y, 3}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}]+
2*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 3}] 
- N1*N1*D[f[y], y]
```

1. I want to integrate the secondary equation over `x=0..1` and `t=0..1` and then plot it against `Q1=-3..3` for three values of `M1=1,2,3` with `y -> 0`.
2. How can I plot contours of `f(x,y)` for fix values of `t=1` and `M1=1`?

Comment: `Zeta` in _Mathematica_ is the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$. You mustn't use it as a constant.

Comment: @Artes thanks for the comment. I have made the changes.

Comment: Avoid using capital letters when assigning constants, Mathematica has an enormous library!

Comment: Where's the value of `a` and `b`? What's the value of `y` in `SE`?

Comment: @xzczd my bad. I have modified the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am very scared of big equations. So whenever I see one, I go numeric (sometimes it is faster also).

```
m = 0.25; \[Phi] = 2 \[Pi]/3; k = 0.8; a = 0.3; b = 0.4;

h1 = -1 - m*x - a*Sin[2*\[Pi]*(x - t) + \[Phi]]
h2 = 1 + m*x + b*Sin[2*\[Pi]*(x - t)]

F1 = Q1 + a*Sin[2*\[Pi]*(x - t)] + b*Sin[2*\[Pi]*(x - t) + \[Phi]]
Z1 = 0.002; N1 = Sqrt[M1^2 + (1/k)];
```

I am going to show one example for

```
M1=1
```

You can use `NDSolve` for a given `Q1`, `x`, and `t` like

```
 Clear[f]
 f[y_] = f[y] /. 
  Block[{Q1 = 1, x = 0.3, t = 0.2}, 
  NDSolve[{f''''[y] + Z1*(6 f''[y]*f'''[y]*f'''[y] + 3 f''[y]*f''[y]*f''''[y]) - 
    N1*N1*f''[y] == 0, f[h2] == F1/2, f[h1] == -(F1/2), f'[h1] == 0, f'[h2] == 0}, 
 f[y], y]];

SE = D[f[y], {y, 3}] + Z1*D[f[y], {y, 3}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}] + 
2*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 3}] -
N1*N1*D[f[y], y];

SE /. y -> 0
```

> -2.44329

You can create a `{x,t,SE}` and use any numerical method to integrate. A lazy person like me will simply use `Sum` (which works nice for small dx and dt)

```
data= Table[
 {Q,

  Sum[
  Clear[f];
  f[y_] = 
   f[y] /. Block[{Q1 = Q, x = x1, t = t1}, 
    NDSolve[{f''''[y] + 
       Z1*(6 f''[y]*f'''[y]*f'''[y] + 3 f''[y]*f''[y]*f''''[y]) - 
       N1*N1*f''[y] == 0,
     f[h2] == F1/2, f[h1] == -(F1/2), f'[h1] == 0, f'[h2] == 0}, 
    f[y], y]][[1]];

SE = D[f[y], {y, 3}] + 
 Z1*D[f[y], {y, 3}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}] + 
 2*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*D[f[y], {y, 2}]*
  D[f[y], {y, 3}] - N1*N1*D[f[y], y];

SE /. y -> 0,

{x1, 0., 1, 0.1}, {t1, 0., 1, 0.1}]}

, {Q, -3., 3., 0.5}]
```

> {{-3., 1134.48}, {-2.5, 855.009}, {-2., 639.126}, {-1.5, 
>     461.605}, {-1., 305.008}, {-0.5, 157.953}, {0., 
>     13.8868}, {0.5, -129.68}, {1., -271.471}, {1.5, -406.275}, {2., \
>   -524.337}, {2.5, -610.275}, {3., -641.51}}

And then a aimple `ListlinePlot`

```
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

For the `ContourPlot`, you can fix a value for `Q1` and generate a `Table` in a same way.

```
M1 = 1; Q0 = 1; t0 = 1;
data = Table[
Clear[f];
f[y_] = 
f[y] /. Block[{Q1 = Q0, x = x1, t = t0}, 
   NDSolve[{f''''[y] + 
       Z1*(6 f''[y]*f'''[y]*f'''[y] + 3 f''[y]*f''[y]*f''''[y]) - 
       N1*N1*f''[y] == 0,
     f[h2] == F1/2, f[h1] == -(F1/2), f'[h1] == 0, f'[h2] == 0}, 
    f[y], y]][[1]];

{x1, y1, f[y1]},

{x1, 0., 1, 0.1}, {y1, 0., 1, 0.1}];
data = Flatten[data, 1]; 

ListContourPlot[data]
```

[image]

For a better result and smoother plot you can reduce the stepsize. I use `0.1`. You can go further below like `0.01` or less (I am too impatient for that). Do some trial value and you can see if your result is varying much due to the change and you can guess the optimum step size.

**For multiple variable**

```
a = 0.3; b = 0.4; m = 0.25; \[Phi] = 2 \[Pi]/3; M1 = 1; k = 0.8;
Nt = 0.8;Nb = 0.4; Pr = 0.2; L = 0.1; Bm = 4; Bh = 2; ;Gr = 0.7;
Br = 1; \[Zeta] = 0.002; Rn = 0.6;

Clear[f1, f2, f3] 
{f1[y_], f2[y_], f3[y_]} = {f1[y], f2[y], f3[y]} /. 
 Block[{Q1 = 1, x = 0.3, t = 0.2, N1 = 0.1, F1 = 0.3}, 
 NDSolve[{f1''''[
      y] + \[Zeta]*(6 f1''[y]*f1'''[y]*f1'''[y] + 
        3 f1''[y]*f1''[y]*f1''''[y]) - N1*N1*f1''[y] + Gr*f2'[y] +
      Br*f3'[y] == 0,
   (1 + 1)*f2''[y] + f3'[y]*f2'[y] + f2'[y]*f2'[y] == 0,
   f3''[y] + f2''[y] == 0,
   f1[h2] == F1/2, f1[h1] == -(F1/2), f1'[h1] == 0,
   f1'[h2] == 0, f3'[h1] == f3[h1], f3'[h2] == (1 - f3[h2]),
   f2'[h1] == Bh*f2[h1], f2'[h2] == (1 - f2[h2])}, {f1[y], f2[y], 
   f3[y]},
  y]][[1]];

{f1[0], f2[0], f3[0]}
```

> {-0.0191435, 0.525077, 0.379438}

Comment: Thanks dear for your efforts. What if we have more than one dependent variables? How we can then write `f[y_] =f[y] /.` for it? It seems that  the rest of  the structure will remain the same.

Comment: Just like that. `f[x1_,x2_,x3_...] = f[x1,x2,x3...]/.`. Make sure the same functional form apears at the end of your `NDSolve`. I would suggest using a region for the `NDSolve`. I mean instead of using `f[y], y]`, use `f[y], {y,-1.,1.}]`. Since the result comes in form of interpolation, this might give you a better (and faster) result.

Comment: I think you miss understood me. If I have three dependent variables say `f1[y], f2[y], f3[y]` then how we will write the functional for this? This is the case when the secondary equation contains all of the three `f1,f2,f3`?

Comment: Got it. Again, just like that. `{f1[y_], f2[y_], f3[y_]} = {f1[y], f2[y], f3[y]}/.`.

Comment: I am getting this error ` Lists {f1[y_],f2[y_],f3[y_]} and {{<<1>>,<<1>>,<<1>>}} are not the same shape.`

Comment: `a = 0.3; b = 0.4; m = 0.25; \[Phi] = 2 \[Pi]/3; M1 = 1; k = 0.8; Nt = 0.8; Nb = 0.4; Pr = 0.2; L = 0.1; Bm = 4; Bh = 2; ;Gr = 0.7; Br = 1; \[Zeta] = 0.002; Rn = 0.6;`

Comment: `Clear[f1, f2, f3]
{f1[y_], f2[y_], f3[y_]} = {f1[y], f2[y], f3[y]} /. 
   Block[{Q1 = 1, x = 0.3, t = 0.2}, 
    NDSolve[{f1''''[
         y] + \[Zeta]*(6 f1''[y]*f1'''[y]*f1'''[y] + 
           3 f1''[y]*f1''[y]*f1''''[y]) - N1*N1*f1''[y] + Gr*f2'[y] + 
        Br*f3'[y] == 
       0, (1 + 1)*f2''[y] + f3'[y]*f2'[y] + 
        f2'[y]*f2'[y] == 0, f3''[y] + f2''[y] == 0, 
      f1[h2] == F1/2, f1[h1] == -(F1/2), f1'[h1] == 0, f1'[h2] == 0, 
      f3'[h1] == f3[h1], f3'[h2] == (1 - f3[h2]), 
      f2'[h1] == Bh*f2[h1], f2'[h2] == (1 - f2[h2])}, {f1, f2, 
      f3}, {y, h1, h2}]];`

Comment: That is because you are missing `[[1]]` after `NDSolve`. Sorry I missed that in the first example. by the way, in this case  `NDSolve` doesn't have a solution. set some value for `N1` and `F1`. and use `{f1[y], f2[y], f3[y]}` in place of  `{f1,f2,f3}`at the end of `NDSolve`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39544/discussion-between-sumit-and-mmm).

Comment: Now it works like a charm. Thanks once again