# Implement NDSolve when I have a very efficient way to compute the right-hand-sides of my coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying speed up `NDSolve` on a set of coupled non-linear second-order ODEs.

```
x[1]''[t] = f[1][x[1],x[2],....]
x[2]''[t] = f[2][x[1],x[2],....]
:
x[n]''[t].....
```

No problem here--these can be dropped right into `NDSolve`.

However, suppose I have very efficient way to compute the `f[i]` terms all-at-once. Can I tell `NDSolve` to take advantage of that function?

---

Here is a concrete "toy" example of what I am asking. (that is, I am asking how to solve a problem of similar character, not this exact problem).

Suppose the force on a particle is proportional to the sum of the lengths to the other particles.  `DistanceMatrix` is very efficient:

```
forces[dofs:{p1:{x1_, y1_}, p2:{x2_, y2_}, p3:{x3_, y3_}}] := 
 Total[DistanceMatrix[dofs]] dofs
```

Here is an example set of degrees of freedom:

```
vars = Flatten[Table[{x[i][t], y[i][t]}, {i, 3}]]
```

And this might be my right-hand-side:

```
 Thread[D[#, {t, 2}] & /@ vars == Table[Inactivate[forces][vars][[i]], {i, 1, 6}]]
```

I believe that this would calculate `force` 6 times and not just once.

Is there a way to "thread" the left-hand-side vector of second derivatives over the function force[..]

Thanks, Craig

Comment: Looks similar to the question I asked at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112887/ndsolve-mixing-many-scalar-and-vector-equations, which I never did pursue further, so I'm interested in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the vectorized version of [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue). Since you don't provide initial conditions, I made some up:

```
SeedRandom[1];
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {
    X''[t] == forces[X[t]],
    X[0] == RandomReal[1, {3, 2}],
    X'[0] == RandomReal[1, {3, 2}]
    },
    X,
    {t,0,1}
];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[
    Evaluate @ Table[Indexed[sol[t], {i,j}], {i,3}, {j,2}],
    {t,0,1}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you Carl Woll! I’ll mark this as solved.

Comment: Future Readers: I was attempting to generalize this to an arbitrary number of degrees of freedom, and I realized I did't understand this completely.  Clear[forces]; forces[dofs_]:=  Total[DistanceMatrix[dofs]] dofs
doesn't work, but this does: Clear[forces]; forces[dofs_?MatrixQ]:=  Total[DistanceMatrix[dofs]] dofs.