# Why does NDSolve need to solve for the derivatives if the equations are already explicitly solved?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Consider the following test case:

```
mMax = 50;
Ffuncs[r_] = Table[F[n, m][r], {n, mMax}, {m, mMax}];
NDSolve[Flatten@{
    Thread[Flatten[D[Ffuncs[r], r]] == Flatten[Ffuncs[r].Ffuncs[r]]],
    Thread[Flatten@Ffuncs[0] == Table[0, {mMax*mMax}]]
    }, Flatten@Ffuncs[r], {r, 0, 2}];
```

When I set `mMax` to `49` or less, it works without any problems. But with `50` or higher, I get

> NDSolve::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.

That was Mathematica 11. Mathematica 9 gives a better message and a better suggestion, which actually works, unlike the suggestion above, which takes forever to complete the solution and eventually crashes the kernel. Here's Mathematica 9's message:

> NDSolve::ndsdtc: The time constraint of 1.` seconds was exceeded trying to solve for derivatives, so the system will be treated as a system of differential-algebraic equations. You can use Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"} to have the system solved as ordinary differential equations. >>

But anyway, I've already gave `NDSolve` a system of equations explicitly solved for derivatives! Why does it still need to solve for derivatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In V10 and higher, you can increase the time limit on `Solve` with the system option `"NDSolveOptions" -> "DefaultSolveTimeConstraint" -> time`:

```
With[{opts = SystemOptions[]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetSystemOptions["NDSolveOptions" -> "DefaultSolveTimeConstraint" -> 10.`],
  sol = NDSolve[
     Flatten@{Thread[
        Flatten[D[Ffuncs[r], r]] == Flatten[Ffuncs[r].Ffuncs[r]]], 
       Thread[Flatten@Ffuncs[0] == Table[0, {mMax*mMax}]]}, 
     Flatten@Ffuncs[r], {r, 0, 2}];,
  SetSystemOptions[opts]
  ]]
(* Spurious message: SystemOptions::noset: ..SystemOption PreemptiveCheckUseThreads..  *)

sol[[1, 1]]
(*  F[1, 1][r] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 2.}}, <>][r]  *)
```

I'm not sure what takes `NDSolve[]` so long, but it's much faster than `Solve[]`:

```
Solve[Thread[Flatten[D[Ffuncs[r], r]] == Flatten[Ffuncs[r].Ffuncs[r]]], 
   Flatten[D[Ffuncs[r], r]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {51.1422, Null}  *)
```

Comment: But _why_ does `NDSolve` even need to solve anything algebraically if the derivatives are already given to it?

Comment: @Ruslan `NDSolve` constructs a function that represents the "right-hand side" of the system ${\bf x}'(r) = f({\bf x}, r)$. It does that by solving the ***equations*** you pass it (I surmise). You don't actually pass derivatives to `NDSolve`. Each expression has `Equal` as its head. It has to inspect them somehow to see what's there. I don't understand why it should take so long, though.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in Mathematica 9 (it continues to complain about 1 second being too small time).

Comment: @Ruslan Hmm, the code works for me without the time constraint option, which doesn't seem to have existed in V9: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4gvHh.png -- But maybe it's solving fast enough on my machine?

Comment: Might be your machine is too fast. Try increasing `mMax`.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, that was it. The workaround `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}` still works.

Comment: @MichaelE2 By replacing `sol=NDSolve[...]` part in your answer in V10, it gives >"The value of SystemOption \!\(\"PreemptiveCheckUseThreads\"\) cannot \
be modified".

Comment: @user55777 I mentioned `SystemOptions::noset` below the code already. Is it a problem for you?

Answer (score 3):

It helps to pose this in vector form, see: [Vector form using NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78641/2079)

This at least doesn't throw the solving for derivatives error. (tested up to 200..)

```
mMax = 60;
vf[vals : {_?NumberQ ..}] := 
 Module[{m = Partition[vals, mMax]}, Flatten[m.m]]

vsoln = NDSolveValue[{x'[r] == vf[x[r]], 
     x[0] == Table[RandomReal[.1], {mMax^2}]}, x[r], {r, 0, 1}];
```

or with the square matix as the unknowm:

```
mMax = 60;
vf[vals : {{_?NumberQ ..} ..}] := vals.vals
vsoln = NDSolveValue[{x'[r] == vf[x[r]], 
    x[0] == Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {mMax}, {mMax}]}, 
    x[r], {r, 0, 1}];
```

I threw in a nonzero initial condition so you get a nonzero result.
you should verify this is doing the right thing, but I think its correct.