# NDSolve - problems solving for coupled vector/matrix equations of high dimension

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I'm trying to solve the following

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} \mu (t) }{\mathrm{d} t} = -\mu (t)+JE $$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} C (t) }{\mathrm{d} t} = JXC(t)+C(t)XJ^T-2C(t)+2TI$$

Where $ \mu $ and E are vectors of dimension $n\times 1$ and $C$, $J$ and $X$ are matrices of dimension $n\times n$ (and $I$ is the identity). $J$ is just sampled from a Gaussian whereas $E$ and $X$ are complicated functions of $ \mu $ and $C$'s coefficients. 
My code pulled up the error

> NDSolveValue::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the
>   derivatives. Consider using the option
>   Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.

So I tried the suggested method and it returned errors `NDSolveValue::nlnum:` and `NDSolveValue::icfail`. I haven't got too much experience with *Mathematica* and so have no idea how to proceed. It's important to note, the matrix $C(t)$ is symmetric which would help things but I don't know how to take this into account. Here's my code:

```
n = 10;
jint = 2;
temp = 0.5;
Jmat = ReplacePart[
RandomVariate[
NormalDistribution[0, jint/Sqrt[n]], {n, n}], {i_, i_} -> 0];
(* The following are the initial conditions *)
mu0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {1, n}];
cov0 = Array[0 &, {n, n}];

funcs1 = Array[mu[#1, #2][t] &, {n, 1}];
funcs2 = Array[cov[#1, #2][t] &, {n, n}];
equations1 = 
Flatten@Join[
Thread[D[funcs1, t] == -funcs1 + 
   Jmat.Erf[Diagonal[Flatten[funcs1]/Sqrt[4/Pi + 2*funcs2]]]], 
Thread[Flatten@funcs1 == Flatten@mu0 /. t -> 0]];
equations2 = 
Flatten@Join[
Thread[D[funcs2, t] == 
  2*temp*IdentityMatrix[n] - 2*funcs2 + 
   Jmat.DiagonalMatrix[
     Sqrt[2/(2 + Pi*Diagonal[funcs2])]*
      Exp[Diagonal[Flatten[funcs1^2]/(4/Pi + 2*funcs2)]]].funcs2 +
    funcs2.DiagonalMatrix[
     Sqrt[2/(2 + Pi*Diagonal[funcs2])]*
      Exp[Diagonal[
        Flatten[funcs1^2]/(4/Pi + 2*funcs2)]]].Transpose[Jmat]], 
Thread[funcs2 == cov0 /. t -> 0]];

sols = NDSolveValue[{equations1, equations2}, {funcs1, funcs2}, {t, 0,
10}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

I've set `n=10` but really I need to look at much higher values.

Any help would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: Your code sample doesn't work, please check it. (The `jmat` and `pi` are suspicious, but this seems not to be the whole story. )

Comment: Sorry about that, I've sorted them out (and edited the code above) and it seems to be running now. Do you have any thoughts/advice on how to a) take into account that funcs2 is symmetric or b) speed the thing up in general? For n=10 it's very fast but unsuprisingly becomes sluggish for higher n.

Comment: Are you sure it works? I think one still needs to modify `Thread[funcs1 == mu0 /. t -> 0]` to `Thread[Flatten@funcs1 == Flatten@mu0 /. t -> 0]`

Comment: It seemed to run but yes thank you, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is strongly related to this one:

[Why does NDSolve need to solve for the derivatives if the equations are already explicitly solved?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131411/1871)

In short, just add `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}` to `NDSolve`/`NDSolveValue`.

When `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` is set, `NDSolve`/`NDSolveValue` will use a DAE solver to solve the equation system. As far as I can tell, the DAE solver of *Mathematica* is still not strong enough for many cases, so my personal suggestion is to stick on the ODE solver as much as possible.

Also, it's possible to make use of the symmetry of `funcs2`. We just need to remove duplicated elements of it, with the help of `UpperTriangularize`, etc.:

```
(* Former part of the code is the same as yours. *)
symRule = DeleteCases[
   Rule @@ (Flatten@UpperTriangularize@# & /@ {funcs2\[Transpose], funcs2}) // Thread, 
   0 -> 0];
equations1 = {Thread[
     D[funcs1, t] == -funcs1 + 
       Jmat.Erf[Diagonal[Flatten[funcs1]/Sqrt[4/Pi + 2*funcs2]]]], 
    Thread[Flatten@funcs1 == Flatten@mu0 /. t -> 0]} //. symRule;

equations2 = 
  DeleteCases[{Thread /@ 
      Thread[UpperTriangularize /@ (D[funcs2, t] == 
          2*temp*IdentityMatrix[n] - 2*funcs2 + 
           Jmat.DiagonalMatrix[
             Sqrt[2/(2 + Pi*Diagonal[funcs2])]*
              Exp[Diagonal[Flatten[funcs1^2]/(4/Pi + 2*funcs2)]]].funcs2 + 
           funcs2.DiagonalMatrix[
             Sqrt[2/(2 + Pi*Diagonal[funcs2])]*
              Exp[Diagonal[Flatten[funcs1^2]/(4/Pi + 2*funcs2)]]].Transpose[Jmat])], 
     Thread /@ Thread[UpperTriangularize /@ (funcs2 == cov0) /. t -> 0]}, True, 
    Infinity] //. symRule;
sols = NDSolveValue[{equations1, 
    equations2}, {funcs1, DeleteCases[Flatten@UpperTriangularize@funcs2, 0]} // 
    Flatten, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know of a way of taking into account/enforcing that funcs2 is symmetric?

Comment: @StressedOutStudent Check my edit.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: By the way, your code above produces the plot much faster than mine in the question - do you know why that is?

Comment: @StressedOutStudent I think it's because my `sols` contains less functions. Notice I've removed those duplicated ones with `DeleteCases[Flatten@UpperTriangularize@funcs2, 0]`. You can also check `Length@Flatten@sols`.

Comment: Sorry one last question, using the code in the original question is it possible to extract individual plots, so for example mu[1][t] or cov[1,2][t], and also to extract data from them at a given time, e.g. mu[2][6] or whatever?

Comment: @StressedOutStudent Of course, and there're many possible ways, for example: `funcmu[2, 1][t_] = 
 sols[[Position[{funcs1, DeleteCases[Flatten@UpperTriangularize@funcs2, 0]} // Flatten, 
      mu[2, 1][t]] // Flatten]] // First; funcmu[2, 1][6]`. (Notice this `sols` is the `sols` in my answer. ) A easier to understand way is to use `NDSolve` and `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) instead, for more information, check document of `NDSolve` carefully.