# Why Mathematica is not producing output and taking too much time

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, education

I'm trying to solve the given system of ODES but the Mathematica is taking too much time and not producing any output. I was trying to check the error by evaluating one one command but there was no error in any command but the equations EOM2, and EOM3 was taking too much time when I was trying to evaluate the equations.

For simple case aa=0, code works, but when I take non-zero aa, it takes a long time and didn't produce output.

Can anyone please guide me how can I fix this problem? Is there any command in Mathematica that can be used to obtain the fast output?

```
 R2[r_, θ_] := r^2 + aa^2 Cos[θ]^2; 
TR[r_, θ_] := r^2 - 2 M r + aa^2;

 gtt[r_, θ_] := -(1 - (2 M r)/R2[r, θ]); 
gtϕ[r_, θ_] := -(( 2 r M aa Sin[θ]^2)/ 
  R2[r, θ]);
gϕϕ[
  r_, θ_] := (r^2 + 
    aa^2 + (2  M r (aa^2) )/ 
     R2[r, θ] Sin[θ]^2) Sin[θ]^2; 
grr[r_, θ_] := R2[r, θ]/TR[r, θ]; 
gθθ[r_, θ_] := R2[r, θ];

 gUtt[r_, θ_] := -(1/
   TR[r, θ]) (r^2 + 
    aa^2 + (2  M r (aa^2) )/ R2[r, θ] Sin[θ]^2); 
gUtϕ[r_, θ_] := -((2 M aa r)/(
  TR[r, θ] R2[r, θ]));

gUϕϕ[r_, θ_] := (
 TR[r, θ] - aa^2 Sin[θ]^2)/(
 TR[r, θ] R2[r, θ] Sin[θ]^2); 
gUrr[r_, θ_] := TR[r, θ]/R2[r, θ]; 
gUθθ[r_, θ_] := 1/R2[r, θ];
M = 1; n = 4;
glo = FullSimplify[{ {gtt[r, θ], 0, 0, 
     gtϕ[r, θ]}, {0, grr[r, θ], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
     gθθ[r, θ], 0}, {gtϕ[r, θ], 0, 0,
      gϕϕ[r, θ]}}];
gup = FullSimplify[{ {gUtt[r, θ], 0, 0, 
     gUtϕ[r, θ]}, {0, gUrr[r, θ], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
     gUθθ[r, θ], 0}, {gUtϕ[r, θ], 0, 
     0, gUϕϕ[r, θ]}}];


dglo = Simplify[Det[glo]]; 
crd = {t, r, θ, ϕ};

Xup = {t[τ], r[τ], θ[τ], ϕ[τ]};
Vup = {Vt, Vr, Vθ, Vϕ};
Pup = {Pt[τ], Pr[τ], Pθ[τ], Pϕ[τ]};

Sup = {{Stt[τ], Str[τ], Stθ[τ], 
    Stϕ[τ]}, 
   {Srt[τ], Srr[τ], Srθ[τ], Srϕ[τ]},
   {Sθt[τ], Sθr[τ], Sθθ[τ],
     Sθϕ[τ]},
   {Sϕt[τ], Sϕr[τ], Sϕθ[τ], 
    Sϕϕ[τ]}};


christoffel = 
  Table[(1/2)*
    Sum[(gup[[i, s]])*(D[glo[[s, k]], crd[[j]] ] + 
        D[glo[[s, j]], crd[[k]] ] - D[glo[[j, k]], crd[[s]] ]), {s, 1,
       n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}] ;


riemann =
  Table[ D[christoffel[[i, j, l]], crd[[k]] ] - 
    D[christoffel[[i, j, k]], crd[[l]] ] + 
    Sum[christoffel[[s, j, l]] christoffel[[i, k, s]] - 
      christoffel[[s, j, k]] christoffel[[i, l, s]],
     {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}] ;


loriemann = 
  Table[Sum[glo[[i, m]]*riemann[[m, j, k, l]], {m, 1, n}], {i, 1, 
    n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}] ;

 EOM1 = Table[ D[Xup[[a]], τ] == Vup[[a]] , {a, 1, n}];


 EOM2 = Table[ 
   D[Pup[[a]], τ] + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(b = 1\), \(n\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(c = 
         1\), \(n\)]christoffel[\([\)\(a, b, c\)\(]\)]*
        Pup[\([\)\(b\)\(]\)]*Vup[\([\)\(c\)\(]\)]\)\) == -(1/2) \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(b = 1\), \(n\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(c = 1\), \(n\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(d = 1\), \(n\)]riemann[\([\)\(a, 
          b, c, d\)\(]\)]*Vup[\([\)\(b\)\(]\)]*
         Sup[\([\)\(c, d\)\(]\)]\)\)\),
   {a, 1, n}];
 EOM3 = Table[ 
   D[Sup[[a, b]], τ] + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(c = 1\), \(n\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(d = 
         1\), \(n\)]christoffel[\([\)\(a, c, d\)\(]\)]*
        Sup[\([\)\(c, b\)\(]\)]*Vup[\([\)\(d\)\(]\)]\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(c = 1\), \(n\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(d = 
         1\), \(n\)]christoffel[\([\)\(b, c, d\)\(]\)]*
        Sup[\([\)\(a, c\)\(]\)]*Vup[\([\)\(d\)\(]\)]\)\) == 
    Pup[[a]]*Vup[[b]] - Pup[[b]]*Vup[[a]],
   {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}];


 Wfactor = 4*μ^2 + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(j = 1\), \(4\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(k = 1\), \(4\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(l = 
         1\), \(4\)]\((loriemann[\([\)\(i, j, k, 
          l\)\(]\)]*\((Sup[\([\)\(i, j\)\(]\)])\)*\ \((Sup[\([\)\(k, 
           l\)\(]\)])\))\)\)\)\)\);

Wvec = Table[2/(μ*Wfactor)*(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(k = 1\), \(4\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(m = 1\), \(4\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(l = 1\), \(4\)]Sup[\([\)\(j, 
           i\)\(]\)]*
          Pup[\([\)\(k\)\(]\)]*\((loriemann[\([\)\(i, k, l, 
            m\)\(]\)])\)*\((Sup[\([\)\(l, m\)\(]\)])\)\)\)\)\)), {j, 
    1, n}];

 NN = 1/Sqrt[1 - \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(k = 
       1\), \(4\)]\((glo[\([\)\(i, k\)\(]\)])\)*Wvec[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)]*
      Wvec[\([\)\(k\)\(]\)]\)\)];


{Vt, Vr, Vθ, Vϕ} = NN (Wvec + Pup);

EOM = Flatten[
   Join[{EOM1, EOM2, EOM3} /. 
        r -> r[τ] /. θ -> θ[τ] /. 
      Derivative[1][r[τ]][τ] -> Derivative[1][r][τ] /. 
     Derivative[1][θ[τ]][τ] -> 
      Derivative[1][θ][τ]]];

INT1 = {t[0] == 0, 
   r[0] == r0, θ[0] == θ0, ϕ[0] == 0};
INT2 = {Pt[0] == 1.32288, Pr[0] == 0, Pθ[0] == 0, 
   Pϕ[0] == 0.07143};
INT3 = {{Stt[0] == 0, Str[0] == 0, Stθ[0] == 0, 
    Stϕ[0] == 0}, 
   {Srt[0] == 0, Srr[0] == 0, Srθ[0] == 0, Srϕ[0] == 0},
   {Sθt[0] == 0, Sθr[0] == 0, Sθθ[0] == 0,
     Sθϕ[0] == 0},
   {Sϕt[0] == 0, Sϕr[0] == 0, Sϕθ[0] == 0, 
    Sϕϕ[0] == 0}};
INT = Flatten[Join[{INT1, INT2, INT3}]];
r0 = 7; θ0 = Pi/2; μ = 1; aa = 0.5; M = 1;

NDSolve[Flatten[Join[{EOM, INT}]], {t, r, θ, ϕ, Pt, Pr, 
  Pθ, Pϕ, Stt, Str, Stθ, Stϕ, Srt, Srr, 
  Srθ, Srϕ,
  Sθt, Sθr, Sθθ, Sθϕ, 
  Sϕt, Sϕr, Sϕθ, Sϕϕ}, {τ, 0, 
  1000}]
```

Comment: Not answer, but the suit of packages xAct might be useful to you: http://www.xact.es/

Comment: @mattiav27 How can I use this package?

Comment: Download the package from http://www.xact.es/download.html and follow the intruction http://www.xact.es/download/install

Comment: It took over 30 minutes just to obtain `EOM`, which has a `LeafCount` of  a staggeringly large `1177079119`.  The problem quickly saturated my 16 GB computer memory.  On this basis, `NDSolve` will take an enormously long time to evaluate.  If you know that any of the dependent variables are identically zero, set them to zero before the computation.  Also, look for ways to simplify intermediate results.  (Applying `Simplify` to `EOM` will take forever itself, however.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in a comment above, `EOM` as computed in the question takes over 30 minutes and has a `LeafCount` of `1177079119`.  These values can be reduced by `FullSimplify`ing `christoffel`. `riemann`. and `loriemann`.  For instance,

```
christoffel = FullSimplify@Table[...]
```

I also replaced `Simplify` by `FullSimplify` in the definition of `dglo`, although doing so did not have a significant impact.  With these changes `EOM` can be computed in a few minutes, and

```
LeafCount[EOM]
(* 23063610 *)
```

which, will still large, is much smaller than before.  Next, for convenience, define

```
var = Join[Xup, Pup, Flatten[Sup]];
```

and solve the 24 ODEs.

```
SetSystemOptions["NDSolveOptions" -> "DefaultSolveTimeConstraint" -> 100.`];
NDSolveValue[Flatten[Join[{EOM, INT}]], var, {τ, 0, 1000}];
```

`SetSystemOptions` is needed to keep `NDSolve` from timing out with the initialization error message, "NDSolve::ntdv", as explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131428/1063).  A plot of the solutions is given by

```
Plot[Evaluate[%[[;; 8]]], {τ, 0, 250}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, 10}, ImageSize -> Large,
    PlotLegends -> Placed[ToString /@ var, {.9, .5}], LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

The remaining variables are identically zero.

```
%% /. τ -> 1000
(* {1269.97, 8.32087, 1.5708, 56.0725, 1.2494, -0.0268073, 7.30725*10^-17, 
    0.0500981, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.} *)
```

Comment: Thanks @bbgodfrey for your answer, it was really helpful.