# Numerically solve a system with 64 equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I'm trying to numerically solve a system of 64 equations (see picture below for the equation, where Erf is the error function and Q is a 64 by 64 matrix). But typing every single equation seems very tedious. So I was wondering (more like hoping) if there is some way to implement this formula in mathematica without explicitly typing all the equations, i.e. using the notion below somehow with e.g. NDSolve?

[image]

Comment: You have to have `Q` defined beforehand; then you can use `Table` to construct a `List` of such equations.

Comment: note the issue that *can* arise with large numbers of equations:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131411/2079

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NDSolve` can work with this in vector form .. see [Vector form using NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78641/2079)

```
n = 64;
lam = .2;
mu = 3;
Q = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
vf[x : {_?NumberQ ..}] := 
 Table[Sum[Q[[i, j]] x[[j]] + mu Q[[i, j]] x[[i]] x[[j]] ,  {j, n}] - 
   lam x[[i]], {i, 64}]
ic = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {n}];

vsoln = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == Erf[vf[x[t]]], x[0] == ic}, x[t], {t, 0, 2}];

Plot[vsoln, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

aside, I'm a bit annoyed I cant figure how to seperately style the output of the resulting vector valued interpolation function..except like this:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[Table[vsoln, {t, 0, 2, .01}]], Joined -> True, 
 DataRange -> {0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant solutions, thanks very much!!

Comment: Try `ListLinePlot@Head@vsoln`.

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1];
n = 2;
μ = RandomReal[];
λ = RandomReal[];
Q = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];

eq = Table[
  x[i]'[t] == 
   Erf @ Sum[Q[[i, j]] x[j][t] + μ Q[[i, j]] x[j][t] x[i][t], {j, 1, n}] - λ x[i][t], {i, 1, n}
      ]

ic = Table[x[i][0] == RandomReal[], {i, 1, n}]

sol = NDSolve[eq~Join~ic, Table[x[i][t], {i, 1, n}], {t, 0, 1}]

func = Table[x[i][t], {i, 1, n}] /. sol

Plot[func, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Works fine when `n = 64`:

[image]

In your real problem you need to, of course, set the values of parameters of interest (i.e., change all `RandomReal`s to what you want/need).

Comment: Nice solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another vector form, without any reference to components, and using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) instead of `Sum`:

```
n = 20;
λ = 1/2;
μ = 3;
SeedRandom[0];
Q = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
ic = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {n}];

vsoln = NDSolveValue[
   {x'[t] == Erf[Q.x[t] + μ Q.x[t] x[t] - λ x[t]], x[0] == ic}, 
   x, {t, 0, 2}];

ListLinePlot[vsoln, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]