# How to solve a vector partial differential equation

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the Fokker-Planck Equation which is used to describe the evolution of orbital dynamics, but I got an error like

> NDSolveValue::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in p[t,{Subscript[r, 1],Subscript[r, 2],Subscript[r, 3],Subscript[v, 1],Subscript[v, 2],Subscript[v, 3]}] should literally match the independent variables.

Main source code is given as below:

```
tmin = 0;
tmax = 60;
x = 
  {Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 2], Subscript[r, 3], 
   Subscript[v, 1], Subscript[v, 2], Subscript[v,3]};
pdf0 = 1/(8 π^3 Sqrt[Det[Σ]])Exp[-(1/2) (x - M).Inverse[Σ].(x - M) ];
sol = 
  NDSolveValue[
    {D[p[t, x], {t}] == LFP[x, p[t, x]], p[0, x] == pdf0},
    p[t, x],
    {t, tmin, tmax},
    {x[[1]], -∞, ∞}, {x[[2]], -∞, ∞}, 
    {x[[3]], -∞, ∞}, {x[[4]], -∞, ∞},
    {x[[5]], -∞, ∞}, {x[[6]], -∞, ∞}]
```

Note that `x` is a 6x1 vector. Σ is a 6x6 covariance matrix and `M` is a 6x1 real vector. As you can see, `pdf0` is the PDF of `MultiGaussian` distribution. `LFP` is a differential operator. I guess this operator is correctly defined since I have tested it with values. There are two questions:

1. How to express the partial differential equation with vectorised form?
2. How to express the natural boundary?

Comment: see here for posing a pde in vector form. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78641/2079  (Actually i,m not sure now if that's relevant. is `p` a vector valued function?)

Comment: The p[t,x] is a scalar function (time variant PDF). I think I need to specify the size of the inputs x(6x1), t (a scalar) and p(t,x) (a scalar function) to Mathematica, but I do not know how. Could you help me? I will go to the page you recommended. Thanks for your reminding and help.

Comment: ok, its not a vector equation, disregard first comment. I've never seen that error, but try `p[t,Sequence@x]` all four places.

Comment: you probably should show `LFP` if that doesnt fix it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the problem is not solved. So I put on the LFP and related functions. Actually, it is a fokker-planck equaiton which is used to describe the revolution of probability density function (pdf) of the state x for a orbital dynamics. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: are you getting the same error?  I think you can not use `D[p,x[[i]]]` inside `LFP` because `x` will have numeric value there, but that is not related to the error in the question.

Comment: Sorry, just looking again that should be `p[t,Sequence@@x]` . The idea being you unknown function is a function with 7 arguments, not two arguments with one argument a list.

Comment: Where's the definition of `Σ`, `M`, `LFP`?