# Continuation of a Problem with Manipulate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, manipulate

For the beginning of this discussion, see: [A problem with Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84307/a-problem-with-manipulate).

Now, the final use of the Initialization command doesn't protect the Global workspace. What I am discussing is not a single Manipulate object. Rather, imagine a notebook filled with static code and many Manipulate objects.

Now, here is an example. Suppose that the values of a and b before performing the Manipulate are assigned as follows:

```
a = 1; b = 5;
```

Then you run the Manipulate object.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
  Graphics[{Table[{Opacity[0.05], EdgeForm[Gray], 
      Rectangle[{a + i dx[n], 0}, {a + (i + 1) dx[n], 
        f[a + (i + 1) dx[n]]}]}, {i, 0, n - 1, 1}], 
    Text["N = " <> ToString[n] <> ",    R = " <> 
      ToString[rightSum[n]], {(a + b)/2, f[b]}]}]], {{n, 10}, 10, 50, 
  10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :> (a = 0; b = 1; dx[n_] := (b - a)/n; f[x_] := x^2;
   rightSum[n_] := N@Sum[f[a + i dx[n]] dx[n], {i, 1, n}])]
```

Now, you are back in your workspace and you enter:

In[37]:= a

Out[37]= 0

In[38]:= b

Out[38]= 1

So, you can see that the Manipulate code affected objects in the workspace. So, question 1 is, what do you add to this code to prevent this from happening.

Here is a second example. Supposed that in the workspace you have defined:

```
dx = (b - a)/n
```

Then you try to run the Manipulate object.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
  Graphics[{Table[{Opacity[0.05], EdgeForm[Gray], 
      Rectangle[{a + i dx[n], 0}, {a + (i + 1) dx[n], 
        f[a + (i + 1) dx[n]]}]}, {i, 0, n - 1, 1}], 
    Text["N = " <> ToString[n] <> ",    R = " <> 
      ToString[rightSum[n]], {(a + b)/2, f[b]}]}]], {{n, 10}, 10, 50, 
  10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :> (a = 0; b = 1; dx[n_] := (b - a)/n; f[x_] := x^2;
   rightSum[n_] := N@Sum[f[a + i dx[n]] dx[n], {i, 1, n}])]
```

Now it doesn't work, sending error messages such as:

Coordinate {(4/$CellContext`n)[10], (4/$CellContext`n)[10]^2} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form. Not only that, but my Documentation notebook is also messed up.

Here is a third problem. Suppose I change the function and a and b in the initialization section to create a new Manipulate. That is, I first do this: set a=0, b=1, and f[x_]:=x^2.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
  Graphics[{Table[{Opacity[0.05], EdgeForm[Gray], 
      Rectangle[{a + i dx[n], 0}, {a + (i + 1) dx[n], 
        f[a + (i + 1) dx[n]]}]}, {i, 0, n - 1, 1}], 
    Text["N = " <> ToString[n] <> ",    R = " <> 
      ToString[rightSum[n]], {(a + b)/2, f[b]}]}]], {{n, 10}, 10, 50, 
  10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :> (a = 0; b = 1; dx[n_] := (b - a)/n; f[x_] := x^2;
   rightSum[n_] := N@Sum[f[a + i dx[n]] dx[n], {i, 1, n}])]
```

Then set a=0, b=2, and f[x_]=x:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
  Graphics[{Table[{Opacity[0.05], EdgeForm[Gray], 
      Rectangle[{a + i dx[n], 0}, {a + (i + 1) dx[n], 
        f[a + (i + 1) dx[n]]}]}, {i, 0, n - 1, 1}], 
    Text["N = " <> ToString[n] <> ",    R = " <> 
      ToString[rightSum[n]], {(a + b)/2, f[b]}]}]], {{n, 10}, 10, 50, 
  10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :> (a = 0; b = 2; dx[n_] := (b - a)/n; f[x_] := x;
   rightSum[n_] := N@Sum[f[a + i dx[n]] dx[n], {i, 1, n}])]
```

If you enter both in a notebook, then evaluate the notebook, you will see that both graphs and values of a and b are the ones defined in the second Manipulate chunk.

So I need to learn more. This is similar to what I posted at: [Difficulty with Manipulate that has same variables as other code lines in a notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78538/difficulty-with-manipulate-that-has-same-variables-as-other-code-lines-in-a-note), but I obviously need to learn more.

What should be added to the Manipulate code to prevent these things from happening?

Comment: You might repeat your experiment with a Manipulate hidden inside a Module. Perhaps that will give you the name isolation that you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would localize the variables inside the `DynamicModule` created by the `Manipulate` by using the `ControlType -> None` (or simply `None` for short) specification. This use is discussed here:

- [What does None mean in a control specification for Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17112/what-does-none-mean-in-a-control-specification-for-manipulate/17113#17113)
- [ControlType -> None Vs. Module inside Manipulate (i.e. making everything local)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72422/controltype-none-vs-module-inside-manipulate-i-e-making-everything-local/72477#72477)

Code:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}],
  Graphics[{
    Table[{Opacity[0.05], EdgeForm[Gray], 
      Rectangle[{a + i dx[n], 0}, {a + (i + 1) dx[n], 
        f[a + (i + 1) dx[n]]}]}, {i, 0, n - 1, 1}],
    Text["N = " <> ToString[n] <> ",    R = " <> 
      ToString[rightSum[n]], {(a + b)/2, f[b]}]
    }]],
 {{n, 10}, 10, 50, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{a, 0}, None}, {{b, 1}, None},
 {{dx, dx}, None}, {{f, f}, None},
 {{rightSum, rightSum}, None},
 Initialization :> (
   a = 0; b = 1;
   dx[n_] := (b - a)/n;
   f[x_] := x^2;
   rightSum[n_] := Total@Table[f[a + i dx[n]] dx[n], {i, 1., n}])]
```

Note that a declaration of the form `{var, None}` is equivalent to `{{var, 0}, None}`, so that the variable `var` would be initialized to `0`. To prevent this, I initialized `dx`, `f`, and `rightSum` to their own symbols.  If they were initialized to `0`, then the definitions, `dx[n_] := ...` etc., would generate errors.  (These initializations happen before the `Initialization` option is evaluated.)

Comment: Oh my goodness! [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72422/controltype-none-vs-module-inside-manipulate-i-e-making-everything-local/72477#72477](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72422/controltype-none-vs-module-inside-manipulate-i-e-making-everything-local/72477#72477) is a blast from the past. I don't remember reading this before. Might have had something to do with Christmas vacation. But it is awesome and I checked it for credit and I'm going to study it in detail tonight. Awesome help Michael. You are really helping me.

Comment: @David  Very glad to help.  Thanks.

Comment: my #1 concern is the writing of notebooks to help students and instructors at our school be introduced to mathematica at a level that is easiest for beginners to understand. One of my favorite books is the Students's Introduction to Mathematica. It has been extremely helpful, but the authors wrap manipulate inside a module and they place modules inside manipulate. Do you have a text recommendation that trains its readers to use the manipulate command at a proper level?

Comment: @David  I don't have a recommendation, and I would expect a book by Bruce Torrence, whom I've met, to be pretty good. `Dynamic` stuff is complicated and constructs that work in a narrow context don't work in a broader one. The notion of "scope" (of a symbol) becomes many times more complicated by `Manipulate` (or `DynamicModule`), and people new at programming find scope a difficult concept even at its simplest. In this context, what you show you're doing in your questions is somewhat sophisticated, probably an appropriate stretch for instructors but perhaps a little much for some students.

Comment: @David You could tell your students & colleagues that any the `Module` outside a `Manipulate` should be a `DynamicModule`.  That would probably work in most/all use-cases and is a fairly straightforward instruction. (Other than initialization, which needs some special care.)

Comment: Based on this comment, I gave your suggestion a try. See: [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84445/does-dynamicmodule-cure-problem-with-manipulate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84445/does-dynamicmodule-cure-problem-with-manipulate)