# How to localize symbols in 'Manipulate'

Tags: manipulate, scoping

I'm confused about the best approach to localizing symbols used in a `Manipulate`. I understand that `Manipulate` does a good job by default of localizing symbols defined in its list of controls (even if these are custom controls). But it appears that symbols defined in the first argument, or those initialized with an `Initialization` option, are not localized. For example, in the following, `z`, `r`, and `q` (and naturally `x`) are local, but `y` and `t` are not:

```
Manipulate[
    y = 4*x;
    Plot[y*x^z+t[q], {x, 0, r}],
    {z, 0, 5},
    Row[{Control@{{r,2}, 2, Dynamic@q}}],
    {{q,10}, 5, 20},
    Initialization:> (t[i_]:=5*i)
]
```

Wrapping the whole `Manipulate` in a `Model[{y,t}, ...` seems to work, but marks `y` and `t` in the `Manipulate` in red (on macOS) which leaves me wondering if it's the right thing to do.

There are [two approaches](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72422/37) that seem to work partially, but not altogether:

#### `DynamicModule`

Wrapping in `DynamicModule` works to localize any symbols not localized by `Manipulate`

```
DynamicModule[{y,t},
    Manipulate[
        y = 4*x;
        Plot[y*x^z+t[q], {x, 0, r}],
        {z, 0,5},
        Row[{Control@{{r,2}, 2, Dynamic@q}}],
        {{q,10}, 5, 20},
        Initialization:> (t[i_]:=5*i)
]]
```

but this places `y` and `t` in an outer scope, which seems the wrong way to proceed.

#### `ControlType -> None`

For some symbols, the form `{sym, None}` works to localize `sym`, but only it seems for limited cases. For example

```
Manipulate[
    y = 4*x;
    Plot[y*x^z+t[q], {x, 0, r}],
    {z, 0, 5},
    Row[{Control@{{r,2},2,Dynamic@q}}],
    {{q,10}, 5,20},
    {y, None},
    Initialization:> (t[i_]:=5*i)
]
```

localizes `y`. But similar attempts to localize a function such as `t` fail.

What is the correct approach to localizing symbols inside `Manipulate`? Is there are reason to prefer `DynamicModule` over `ControlType -> None` in general, or vice versa? How should local functions be localized (esp. if the natural thing to be ding is specifying them in `Initialization`)?

---

Additionally, controls defined with `Control@` [don't highlight the associated symbols to indicate localization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155177/37), which makes it very hard to read through code and understand how things are scoped. `DynamicModule` can be used to fix this (and even leaves the symbol in the inner `Manipulate` scope).

Comment: `Manipulate` only localizes control variables. If you want more localization see `DynamicModule`. Since `Manipulate` is a front-end thing (it's a cousin of `Dynamic`) you'll want the front-end version of `Module`--i.e. `DynamicModule`. In fact `Manipluate` resolves to a `DynamicModule` when viewed.

Comment: To localize, for example `r`, you can add `{{r, 2}, None}` after `{{q, 10}, 5, t}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65132/discussion-between-b3m2a1-and-raxacoricofallapatorius).

Comment: Closely related: [17112](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17112/5478), [72422](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72422/5478)

Comment: Also related: [13658](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13658), It is possible that much of what is discussed in the comments has been fixed in the intervening (nearly) five years.

Answer (score 5):

Because of the interactions of the various sliders, I would wrap the `Manipulate` expression in a `DynamicModule` expression that defines and localizes `y` and `t`. I would also define `y` as a function. Like so:

```
DynamicModule[{y, t},
  Manipulate[
    Plot[y[x]*x^z + t[q], {x, 0, r}],
    {z, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    Row[{Control @ {{r, 2}, 2, q, Appearance -> "Labeled"}}],
    {{q, 5}, 5, t[i], Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{i, 3}, 1, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
  Initialization :> (y[x_] := 4*x; t[i_] := 5*i)]
```

[image: demo]

I had to introduce the `i` slider because, without something like it, the OP's code as given in the question is not functional.

#### Update

My experience is that the form `{{var, intitVal}, None}` works well when `var` is used to introduce a simple variable, such as temporary used to help break up a complicated computation. To localize more complex things, such as function definitions, I prefer to take the route I show in this answer.

Comment: Fixed the bug in the code. Also focused on the several issues raised.

Comment: And `r`? What's the reason for the different coloring; is it meant to mean something? `DynamicModule` fixes it (and even keeps it in the the right scope).

Comment: So this method appears superior in terms of brevity and clarity. Is there any real drawback to pulling things — here `y` and `t` — out into a new nesting scope?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius. Not that I know of.

Answer (score 3):

The `{var, None}` spec does work for functions if you use `Clear`. It just initially assigns `0` to them. So you can do this:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[y[x]*x^z + t[q], {x, 0, r}], {z, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Row[{Control@{{r, 2}, 2, q, Appearance -> "Labeled"}}], {{q, 5}, 5, 
  t[i], Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{i, 3}, 1, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {y, None},
 {t, None},
 Initialization :> (
   Clear[y, t];
   y[x_] := 4*x; t[i_] := 5*i)
 ]
```

Comment: And `r`? What's the reason for the different coloring? (It seem the only way to avoid it is with `DynamicModule`; or initializing it a second time in a `ControlType -> None` control.)

Comment: What's wrong with `r`? It's colored differently because it doesn't match `SyntaxInformation[Manipulate]`.

Comment: That's a bit circular though. The question is: if the coloring is meant to convey something, what is it meant to convey? Locals are clearly indicated, as are undefined symbols. The coloring for `r` corresponds to the latter.

Comment: The coloring isn't handled by the kernel at all. It's handled by the front-end. The front end does static analysis to try to figure out what is what, but the front end is sometimes wrong. The coloring should be seen as a guideline. Usually the FE is right, but sometimes it misses things.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes more sense: it's wrong.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius sorry I thought I had made that clear in chat. In any case, might be worth reading up on the FE and the kernel. Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems that `{{y,y},None}` and `{{t,t},None}` also works and eliminates the need for `Clear` without requiring repeating a specific value for the control initialization.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius makes sense